# Implementing Gradient Descent In Python and receiving an overflow error

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, gradient-descent, loss-function

### Gradient Descent and Overflow Error

I am currently implementing vectorized gradient descent in python. However, I continue to get an overflow error. The numbers in my dataset are not extremely large though. I am using this formula:

[image: Formula for vectorized gradient descent]
 I choose this implementation to avoid using derivatives. Does anyone have any suggestion on how to remedy this problem or am I implementing it wrong? Thank you in advance!

Dataset Link: https://www.kaggle.com/CooperUnion/anime-recommendations-database/data

```
## Cleaning Data ##
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('anime.csv')
# print(data.corr())
# print(data['members'].isnull().values.any()) # Prints False
# print(data['rating'].isnull().values.any()) # Prints True

members = [] # Corresponding fan club size for row 
ratings = [] # Corresponding rating for row

for row in data.iterrows():
    if not math.isnan(row[1]['rating']): # Checks for Null ratings
        members.append(row[1]['members'])
        ratings.append(row[1]['rating'])


plt.plot(members, ratings)
plt.savefig('scatterplot.png')

theta0 = 0.3 # Random guess
theta1 = 0.3 # Random guess
error = 0
```

### Formula's

```
def hypothesis(x, theta0, theta1):
    return  theta0 + theta1 * x

def costFunction(x, y, theta0, theta1, m):
    loss = 0 
    for i in range(m): # Represents summation
        loss += (hypothesis(x[i], theta0, theta1) - y[i])**2
    loss *= 1 / (2 * m) # Represents 1/2m
    return loss

def gradientDescent(x, y, theta0, theta1, alpha, m, iterations=1500):
    for i in range(iterations):
        gradient0 = 0
        gradient1 = 0
        for j in range(m):
            gradient0 += hypothesis(x[j], theta0, theta1) - y[j]
            gradient1 += (hypothesis(x[j], theta0, theta1) - y[j]) * x[j]
        gradient0 *= 1/m
        gradient1 *= 1/m
        temp0 = theta0 - alpha * gradient0
        temp1 = theta1 - alpha * gradient1
        theta0 = temp0
        theta1 = temp1
        error = costFunction(x, y, theta0, theta1, len(y))
        print("Error is:", error)
    return theta0, theta1

print(gradientDescent(members, ratings, theta0, theta1, 0.01, len(ratings)))
```

### Error's

After several iterations, my costFunction being called within my gradientDescent function gives me an OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large'). However, I expect my code to continually print out a decreasing error value.

```
    Error is: 1.7515692852199285e+23
    Error is: 2.012089675182454e+38
    Error is: 2.3113586742689143e+53
    Error is: 2.6551395730578252e+68
    Error is: 3.05005286756189e+83
    Error is: 3.503703756035943e+98
    Error is: 4.024828599077087e+113
    Error is: 4.623463163528686e+128
    Error is: 5.311135890211131e+143
    Error is: 6.101089907410428e+158
    Error is: 7.008538065634975e+173
    Error is: 8.050955905074458e+188
    Error is: 9.248418197694096e+203
    Error is: 1.0623985545062037e+219
    Error is: 1.220414847696018e+234
    Error is: 1.4019337603196565e+249
    Error is: 1.6104509643047377e+264
    Error is: 1.8499820618048921e+279
    Error is: 2.1251399172389593e+294
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "tyreeGradientDescent.py", line 54, in <module>
        print(gradientDescent(members, ratings, theta0, theta1, 0.01, len(ratings)))
      File "tyreeGradientDescent.py", line 50, in gradientDescent
        error = costFunction(x, y, theta0, theta1, len(y))
      File "tyreeGradientDescent.py", line 33, in costFunction
        loss += (hypothesis(x[i], theta0, theta1) - y[i])**2
    OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Comment: Is your neural network very deep? If so, you could be running to the exploding gradients problem: https://machinelearningmastery.com/exploding-gradients-in-neural-networks/ there's several different ways to try to avoid this - by using a good initializer for example.

Comment: To which competition does this apply?

Comment: @enumaris It is not in a neural net I was interested in implementing gradient descent. Also, thanks for the article I am looking at it now.

Comment: @Prune it is not for any competition.

Comment: Where is the overflow error?  What debugging output do you have?  Where does it start to diverge from your expectations?  In short, your posting isn't yet up to SO standards.

Comment: @Prune I updated the post and I receive an OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large') the error comes after several iterations of my gradient descent function. The exact function that throws the error is the costFunction. However, I expected to see my costFunction constantly return a decreasing value for the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your data values are really very large, which makes your loss function very steep. The result is that you need a *tiny* alpha unless you normalize your data to smaller values. With an  alpha value that is too large your gradient descent is hopping all over the place and actually diverges, which is why your error rate is going up rather than down.

With your current data, an alpha of `0.0000000001` will make the error converge. After 30 iterations my loss went from :

`Error is: 66634985.91339202`

to

`Error is: 16.90452378179708`

Comment: How were you able to find the appropriate alpha value?

Comment: @user3697597 I couldn't see another error in your code. If the code is correct and the loss is not decreasing, a alpha of too large a value should be the first suspect. So i just lowered it until it started to behave.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

X = [0.5, 2.5]
Y = [0.2, 0.9]

def f(w, b, x): #sigmoid with parameter w,b
    return 1.0/(1.0 * np.exp(-(w * x + b)))


def error(w, b):
    err = 0.0
    for x, y in zip(X, Y):
        fx = f(w, b, x)
        err += 0.5 * (fx - y)**2
    return err

def grad_b(w, b, x, y):
    fx = f(w, b, x)
    return (fx - y) * fx * (1 - fx)

def grad_w(w, b, x, y):
    fx = f(w, b, x)
    return (fx - y) * fx * (1 - fx) * x

def do_gradient_descent():
    w, b, eta, max_epochs = 1, 1, 0.01, 100
    for i in range(max_epochs):
        dw, db = 0, 0
        for x, y in zip(X, Y):
            dw += grad_w(w, b, x, y)
            db += grad_b(w, b, x, y)
        w = w - eta * dw
        print(w)
        b = b - eta * db
        print(b)
    er = error(w, b)
    #print(er)
    return er
##Calling Gradient Descent function
do_gradient_descent()
```